# _getch not reading input into variable

Tags: c++, getch

I'm having trouble with the _getch() function, I want it so that the user does not need to hit ENTER when selecting things from the menu. However, when I try and use it, it either doesn't input the data into a variable, or it skips over the switch I have. I'm using Windows 7, and the CodeBlocks IDE. What am I doing incorrectly? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

stringstream ss;
int a;

void play()
{
  cout << "\nYou wake up on the forest floor. You do not remember where you are, who you are, or anything\nthat has happened before you waking up. You seem to be some type of...\n";
  cout << "--CHARACTER SELECTION--\n1. Warrior\n2. Mage\n3. Rouge";
  cin.get();
};


int main()
{
//  CreateDirectory()
  cout << "--SELECTION MENU--\n1. Begin\n2. Delete Game\n3. Instructions" << endl;
  a=_getch();


  switch(a){

  case 1:
  play();
  break;

  case 2:
 // delete();
  break;

  case 3:
 // help();
  break;
  return 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Compare your char against the characters `'1'`, `'2'` and `'3'` rather than the integers `1`, `2` and `3`.

```
switch(a){

  case '1':
  play();
  break;

  case '2':
 // delete();
  break;

  case '3':
 // help();
  break;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That didn't help with the _getch() part, but I can see where it could cause problems in the future. Thanks!

EDIT: I see! Thanks! That fixed it.